# CameraCaptureUI control size of popup?

Tags: win-universal-app, uwp

A couple of questions about CameraCaptureUI.

1) Can I control the size/placement of the popup?  It pops up very small on my Win10 tablet and it's really annoying to enlarge it each time the app needs to take a photo!

2) I am trying to create photos that are equivalent in quality to the built-in camera app, but I had a lot of trouble with this.  Only by playing around with the croppedSizeInPixels could I get anything larger that seemed decent quality.  Can someone explain why this helped and if there's a better way to increase the quality of the photo?  The builtin app creates 2592x1944 pixel images approx 1MB large by default.  IF this is the right way should I be calculating these dimensions somehow?

```
captureUI = new CameraCaptureUI();
captureUI.PhotoSettings.Format = CameraCaptureUIPhotoFormat.Jpeg;
captureUI.PhotoSettings.AllowCropping = true;
captureUI.PhotoSettings.MaxResolution = CameraCaptureUIMaxPhotoResolution.HighestAvailable;

// photo created is approx 576KB
captureUI.PhotoSettings.CroppedSizeInPixels = new Size(3840, 2160);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1) Can I control the size/placement of the popup?

As you can see, there is no API in [CameraCaptureUI class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.media.capture.cameracaptureui.aspx) can control the size/placement of the camera capture UI. For Windows 8.1, this class provides a full window UI for capturing audio, video, and photos from a camera. However, in Windows 10, it's a popup windows. Actually, this class launches the built-in Camera app for capturing, you can find this in Task Manager.

If `CameraCaptureUI` can't meet your requirement and you want more robust, low-level control of the capture operation, you should use the [**MediaCapture**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br241124) object and implement your own capture experience. For more information, see [Capture photos and video with MediaCapture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/capture-photos-and-video-with-mediacapture).

> 2) I am trying to create photos that are equivalent in quality to the built-in camera app.

`CameraCaptureUI` class actually launches the built-in Camera app for capturing and it doesn't provide much ways to specify properties for the returned photo. We can only use **[CroppedSizeInPixels](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br241044)** to specify the resolution of the captured photo. We can set this property to a large enough value. If a size is specified that is larger than any available resolution, then the captured photo will be scaled to a large enough size first. If you want to control the resolution of the captured picture, I'd also recommend using MediaCapture with [**GetMediaStreamProperties**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.media.devices.videodevicecontroller.getmediastreamproperties.aspx) and [**SetMediaStreamPropertiesAsync**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh700895.aspx) methods. For more info, please see [Camera resolution sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraResolution).

Comment: Thanks!  I have written a MediaCapture implementation (largely stolen from that sample), but was hoping to switch over.   I love the cropping feature available by default in the CameraCaptureUI class and that seems very time-consuming to try and reproduce with the MediaCapture.