# cordova-camera-plugin opens windows 10 camera in small window

Tags: windows, cordova, plugins, camera

I have created the cordova solution using cordova-camera-plugin which opens device camera on click of button. The solution works fine on windows 8.1 surface. Camera opens in full screen mode. But when I use the same solution for Windows 10, it opens camera in small window.

Is there any way to open camera in full screen mode?

I am running the application in table mode of windows 10. I have tried With the latest version of cordova[6.X] and camera plugin[3.2], but the behavior is same.

Comment: I am having the same problem but I think it's not possible with the curent CaptureCamerUI API. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38688586/cameracaptureui-control-size-of-popup)